# Basic property of definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$$
is integrated from $x=0$ to $x$ to yield
$$
y(x)-y(0)=F(x)-F(0)
$$
where
$$
F(x)-F(0)=\int_0^xf(x)dx 
$$
is it true that $y(0)=F(0)$ and $y(x)=F(x)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. FYI, you should be careful with your use of variables as what you've written is somewhat confusing. For example, you wrote "... integrated from $x = 0$ to $x$ ...". How can what you're changing and the end point be the same variable? Also, you write $\int_0^x f(x)dx$, but the $x$ as the upper point of integration and the $x$ being integrated are actually $2$ different variables. As such, it would be more clear to use something like $\int_0^x f(z)dz$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, $y$ and $F$ could differ by a constant.